# can I change rest model state without using .set()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have model with custom attribute(array of objects). Like this

```
App.Adapter.registerTransform('images', {
    serialize: function(value) {
        var ret = []
        value.forEach(function(img){
            ret.pushObject(img.get('uuid'))
        })
        if (ret.get('length')) {
            return ret.join(',')
        } else 
        return false
    },
    deserialize: function(value) {
        ret = []     
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined') {
            uuids = value.split(',')
            for (var i = 0; i < uuids.length; i++) {
                var id = uuids[i]
                ret.pushObject( App.Image.create({'uuid': id}) )
            }
        }
        return ret
    }
})
```

And my model.

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    …
    images:         DS.attr('images')
})
```

in controller I need commit data, after pushing changes in this property. What I need to do for this case?

```
uploadImage: function(){
    var self = this

    uploading.done(function(result) {
            self.get('images').pushObject(App.Image.create({uuid:result.uuid}))
            console.log(self.get('isDirty')) // false
            self.get('store').commit() //nothing to change
    }).fail(function(result) {
     …
    }).always(function() {
     …
    })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do this?

```
self.notifyPropertyChange('images');
```